# Calling stored procedure with parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure that returns a value, not a dataset, and I have problems getting it to work with EF4.

I've seen this: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/how-retrieve-stored-procedure

Here is what I did: I added a procedure to the model, and imported a function.

The first issue that I had was the fact that parameters in my procedure are named like `@_Parameter_in`. That made EF to bring them in as `p_Parameter_in` because it wouldn't work with an underscore as the first character. Then when I called the stored procedure, I can see in the SQL Profiler call that it looks for `@p_Parameter_in`, and of course there was an issue with that.

Now I renamed the parameters and looked into SQL Trace - everything looks and works great. The problem is that I can't get the value out. Here is how my code looks:

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter newKey = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("NewKey_out", typeof(Int32));
newKey.Value = 0;
context.GetNextSurrogateKey_v2("tTest", newKey);
```

After calling `newKey.Value`, it's always 0 or whatever value I set it to. It doesn't bring the value back.  I suspect my issue is with how I import the function. I use Scalars and data type `Int32`. "Create new Complex type" is disabled for me for some reason. Anybody had that issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing here since I can't see the stored procedure that you're calling. I think you're wanting to retrieve a scalar value that has been returned by the stored procedure, rather than the value of an output parameter as defined in the stored procedure.

I believe you want to define a new Function within the EDM and point this at the stored procedure. A quick google has this potential solution: http://www.devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values

HTH

Comment: That is something to look at, I may just modify procedure to work like this. Currently I do not return scalar value. I assign value to OUTPUT parameter in stored procedure.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I get error "The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested"

Comment: Ok, I made it to work. With placing select @MyValue at the end of stored proc. The question is still open if it's possible to use OUTPUT parameters with EF..

Comment: Just to be clear, is newkey_out marked with the 'ouput' keyword in the stored procedure and is a value selected to it?

Comment: yes, it was marked at output. This stored proc been there forewer since plan ADO and LINQtoSQL times.

I ended up doing SELECT newkey_out at the end of proc (getting dataset essentialy) and used scalar output type in EF. That fixed it but I don't like it :( I wish there was a way to call it as it was. With parameter names as it was. We have tons of code on DB side and naming convention was @_Parameter_in and @_Parameter_out. EF wouldn't work with names. I will mark your answer since I made it to work thanks to your link

Comment: @christo8989 yeah I'm seeing something wrong as well. Not my site I'm afraid - it's been registered for years (https://who.is/whois/devtoolshed.com) so guess it must have been hacked somehow.

Comment: A snapshot of the linked article in this answer is available here.  https://web.archive.org/web/20110620073108/http://www.devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that EF process output parameters after datareader ends reading. That's usually  after calling DataBind() function.
I had same problem with longer processing procedures. I solve this by using .ToList() function on ObjectResult.

```
var rowsCount = new ObjectParameter("RowsCount", typeof(Int32));    
var result = db.GetProductList(pageSize, pageNumber, rowsCount).ToList();
this.ProductsCount = (int?)rowsCount.Value;
```

Single rows or values can you probably solve with FirstOrDefault() function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as Jan Remunda described.  Someone changed the return type from Integer to Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult(of Integer?) which resulted in always returning nothing.

For us the solution was to force EF to read the return of the stored proc by adding the .FirstOrDefault() function to the return.