# The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I am using Entity Framework. I have created an entity object called Customer and added my Stored proc.

My stored procedure contains another two stored procedure which returns some string in output parameter. And I concatenate the output parameter value of both Stored procedure in the main stored procedure.

Main stored procedure returns the resultant string in output parameter as well.

Also I created a function import for the main stored procedure to return the concatenated string.

When I run my application I get "The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested."

I don't have select statement in the first and second procedures. Let me know how I return the output parameter value of the main stored procedure.

Find more Information below.

```
Create Procedure MainProcedure
@Id int,
@MainResult nvarchar(max) output
AS
Begin
declare @firstResult nvarchar(max)
declare @secondResult nVarchar(max)
declare @MainResult nVarchar(max)

Exec FirstSP @Id,@firstResult Output
Exec SecondSP @Id,@secondResult Output

Set @MainResult=@firstResult+@secondResult

End
```

Entity Code looks like

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<string> resultList = null;
     var OutputParamter =new ObjectParameter("MainResult",typeof(string));
        resultList = ent.MainProcedure(ID, OutputParamter);
```

Comment: Your going to need to post some code for this, can you please post: a table structure for the result of the stored proc, the entity you are loading the result into and your execSql code

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Please find the edited question.

Comment: Sorry guys I have added "Select @MainResult" after setting the value to MainResult. Now it's started working. Now another issue when I do unit testing for the FirstSP stored procedure it returned me the error 'The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested.'And then I added the Select FirstResult in the FirstSP. Now if I run MainProcedure Unit test it return me the FirstSP result but not the complete. How to achive this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling stored procedure with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068212/calling-stored-procedure-with-parameters)

Answer (score 4):

I can't see your stored procedures to help you more, but this error faced me when I used stored procedure,and tried to get returned value through "return" statement Like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table) 
    return 0
```

this works fine on sql server but with EF it doesn't.

the solution for me was by replace return statement with select statement, like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table) 
    --return 0
    select @OUTPUT=0
```

this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/538200/Returningplusoutputplusandplusreturnplusvalueplusf) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Same error for me.  I was calling an SP using EF 5 and the SP was executing another SP but the last SELECT to return the value which EF was expecting, was commented.  Here's an example of what it looks like inside the SP executed by EF

```
exec another SP
--SELECT @ReturnValue AS OrderNo
```

Upon uncommenting the SELECT it worked like a charm